# Testing enum gives warning: comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: objective-c, iphone, enums

I am getting this warning:

> warning: comparison between pointer
>   and integer

when doing the following:

```
if (menuItem.menuType == LinkExternal)
```

MenuType is a custom enum defined as below:

```
enum menuItemType
{
    LinkInternal = 0,
    LinkExternal = 1,
    Image = 2,
    Movie = 3,
    MapQuery = 4
};

enum menuItemType *menuType;
```

I assume I just need a cast but what is the syntax?

Comment: Please show the declaration of `menuItem.menuType`, not just `enum menuItemType`.  I'm wondering if you declared it as `menuItemType* menuType;` instead of `menuItemType menuType`.

Comment: So... since you declared it as a pointer to a `menuItemType`, where do you allocate the `menuItemType` it points to?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As your menuType is a pointer to enum value you can rewrite your condition:

```
if (*(menuItem.menuType) == LinkExternal)
```

But why do you need to store this value by pointer? Can't you have just:

```
enum menuItemType menuType;
```